# Toilet blocked and need to unblock

Tags: home

my toilet is kind of blocked. If I try to flush it normally, the water doesn’t go through, it kind of fills the bowl and then slowly drained. But if I just poor a bucket of water into it, then the water goes through with the feces like how it is suppose to. I tried using baking soda+ vinegar , pumps, hooks from cloth hanger, bleach and it still can’t be flushed normally. I think the toilet is partially blocked so that the pressure generated from pouring a bucket of water quickly into the bowl is enough to do the job but the pressure from the flush is not enough. What next?

Comment: Hi user42493, Welcome to lifehacks. If the water goes through when you pour water into the bowl, it is not blocked. It is not getting water from the supply to fill the tank behind the toilet. Remove the tank cover and verify it is full before you try to flush. Is the toilet tank full? Add more information (using edit) to your question details.

Comment: If the toilet was blocked, trying to flush it would be rather unpleasant as the contents would back-up and overflow the tank so long as the tank refilled. In that case, you would want a plunger.

Comment: This is not really a question well suited to lifehacks.stackexchange - it is more of a plumbing problem and would perhaps be better posted on homeimprovement. If you were asking for how to make something to unblock a toilet then it would be more like a life hack but we aren't even certain that it is actually blocked because you say that a bucket of water goes down fine but a flush of water (which, let's face it, isn't any different to a bucket, if your toilet has a cistern: cistern=bucket, flush=pour) doesn't. i recommend you post a video of a flush vs a bucket so we can see the difference

Comment: Did you try a manual **toilet plunger**?

Answer (score 3):

When you release water into the toilet bowl by using the toilet flush handle, it is opens a drain using a link to a plunger inside the bottom of the toilet tank.

If the plunger does not open fully, there will not be enough water to flush the toilet.

You can verify this by watching as you twist the handle to flush the toilet. Let the tank fill. Flush. Watch the action without the cover on the tank.

Maybe the link is broken or stretched. It might have become partly detached from the drain cover. The cover may be torn. I think that's where the problem may lie.

After the tank refills, try pouring water directly into the bowl to see the difference.

Good luck.

Comment: By the way @user42493, You have discovered a hack for flushing a toilet when there is no water available in the plumbing system. You can flush directly this way.

Comment: Don't forget, not every toilet has a cistern

Answer (score 2):

If some water is getting through then the blockage is probably temporary. You can speed it up in a few ways.

- Commercial toilet unblockers are based on caustic soda. You can get it cheaper in hardware stores or online.
- Try pouring in a bucket of hot water. Don't do this if you have added caustic soda
- If you have one available you can use a hose to run in a continuous stream of water
- Blockages in toilets are likely to be biological in origin. Add some biological detergent and leave it overnight
- In future remember this advice https://wearethecity.com/the-funniest-sign-we-have-seen-in-ages-virgin-trains-notice/

Comment: Hi Bernard, Welcome to Lifehacks. Don't forget to look at the [Tour] and [Help] for how to get the most that this site has to offer. You also get some reputation points for the effort.

Comment: @Stan actually, they only get a badge. But it's good advice nonetheless :)